# software for rack visualisation

Tags: networking, datacenter, rack, rackmount, visualization

Can you recommend any (preferably open-source) software for server racks visualization? Ideally it should be able to draw cable links between pieces of equipment, and should be scriptable to some extent (or at least take as an input hardware and links description in some well-defined format).

Edit: I'm interested in a solution which does not require MS Windows - we are a no windows shop.

Comment: Now this becomes funny: adding a "no windows" requirement instantly produced a downvote.

Comment: No, the downvotes were likely because you didn't make it obvious what OS you were using. People tend to "default" towards Windows, hence why the answer suggested a Windows packages.

Comment: @tombull89, Anyway, the amount of downvotes is quite surprising for me. Really, is visualization of racks considered to be a bad practice?..

Comment: @abbot - it's shopping which is OT on server fault, and your question is an example of no research effort imho. Hence the downvote from me. A question that showed that you'd found a couple of options and were asking for clarification of some difference between them might be received very differently.

Answer (score 3):

MS Visio combined with the make/model specific shapes found at visiocafe.com is the generally accepted combination around here.

Comment: Would adding a "No windows software please" requirement to much to ask?

Comment: I didn't downvote you but you should have mentioned that initially. How about using Graffle, unless you're a no osx shop too, in fact why not state what OS you want rather than what you don't want.

Comment: OSX is fine, but I'd really prefer to see something open source so I could properly integrate it into other tools we are using. I really don't understand why people downvote this question, is visualizing racks with non-windows software considered to be a bad practice?..

Comment: No, but not adding a KEY detail is understandably annoying as you get people putting their efforts into answering a question in good faith then getting shot down as their crystal ball failed them.